# In visual studio how can you see the outliner when loading an arm template into visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Ive loaded an ARM template into Visual Studio called armtemplate.json but can see the outliner on the left which shows parameters, variables and resources etc

Does someone know how to enable this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for how to enable the JSON Outliner if it’s not displayed by default. 
Below screenshot should help you navigate

1. Right click on .json file
2. You should see the option of Show outline and click on it
3. You should be able to view the JSON Outline on the left hand pane.

[image]

But if you are looking for something else, please elaborate your question so we can better understand and try to answer your question.